# CloudFormation create initial SSM parameter but allow future updates from UI console

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

I'm trying to figure the proper way of managing CloudFormation templates when SSM parameters are updated from AWS Console/UI and not always ported back to CloudFormation templates in `Value` attributes.

Perhaps those parameters should be created manually instead and referenced via `resolve` dynamic references? Or should this be "import existing AWS resources" into stack instead?

The reason why I went with SSM & CF is because I wanted to version control *parameter names* and not necessarily parameter values.

Comment: What do you do exactly that results in "Parameter Name /foo with a different configuration already exists"? Changing param values in AWS console should not produce such an error.

Comment: @Marcin hi Marcin. I've just updated the question to exclude that quoted error that I think might have been caused by some drafted manual conflicted updates. The main question persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFormation will resolve the parameter values when it is creating or updating the stack. Any changes to the parameters that you are referencing, will not signal the CloudFormation stacks to be updated. As is stated in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html) as follows:

> When you use a dynamic reference, CloudFormation retrieves the value of the specified reference when necessary during stack and change set operations.

So any time you update the parameter value, you have to update the stack. You can either do this manually or create some kind of automation e.g., using CloudTrail and Lambda.